Documentary that I think I saw in the late 90s about long runout landslides
In what I want to say was the late 1990s, I saw a documentary in New Zealand on the peculiar phenomenon of "long runout" landslides, which as I recall are slides that travel several times further across the landscape than expected given the height from which they slip. I distinctly remember there was a segment on the Mount St. Helens flank collapse. There was also the first time I heard about Hawaii's great crack.
I'm not sure if the crack was before or after a section on the seafloor mapping the US government did around Hawaii before it became a state and the ancient landslides that it revealed. Part of the documentary was also about some very early particle motion computer simulations as scientists tried to understand the mechanism(s) that lead to the unusual behaviour of the slides.
I don't know if this was a one-off or part of a series like National Geographic, but I think it was on at a time that I wouldn't normally watch documentaries. So if it was a series, it may have been the first episode of a new season, or it was played as a one-off for some reason.
Can anyone identify this documentary?

a quick search using "long runout landslides tv documentary" gives a BBC documentary (and others) that could match, no?

@OldPadawan I tried a nearly identical search term (long runout landslide documentary) but didn't get the BBC Horizon result, which, having skimmed it on YouTube, is indeed the one I was looking for.

@OldPadawan - Needs posting as an answer :-)

@Valorum Very much so, but I'm brand new here so I wasn't going to get too pushy.

@Ash - You're always welcome to post it as a self-answer. Putting "thank you to x for their comment" is sufficient to satisfy honour

@Valorum I'll give them until the 24 hour mark then I shall do that.

Many thanks to @OldPadawan for their comment, they have demonstrated superior Google Fu. The documentary I was looking for is BBC Horizon's The Runaway Mountain made in 1995. I probably saw it a couple of years later.
